# Adding prefix to command output based on finding match in the output.

Tags: sed

I need a way to rework a command line output, to add a prefix to it. I think I am just not understanding the SED syntax needed to make this work.

The goal is a bash shell which will quickly display Active WebSphere profiles on a particular server.

My first attempt uses ps -ef command, to display active process followed by grep command to display only processes of interest. This pulled the desired results, but the last column of ps -ef command is too long to be of value.

By the way, I am running on AIX, egrep -o is not an option for me.

My second attempt was to use sed -n command to search the command output string for just the profiles of interest. This got me closer to desired result.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

body() {
    # print the header (the first line of input)
    # and then run the specified command rest of the input
    # Usage example  ps | body grep somepattern
    IFS= read -r header
    printf '%s\n' "$header"
    "$@"
}

echo -e "\n-----------------------";
grepString="Cog[CGR][MWS][123]Profile"   ## Regular Expression for names of WebSphere profiles

# first attempt
ps -ef | ( body egrep $grepString | sort -k5 )  | cut -c1-180

# second attempt
ps -ef | ( body sed -n "s/.*\($grepString\).*/\1/p" | sort -k1 )
```

My Second attempt produced results like:

```
     UID     PID    PPID   C    STIME    TTY  TIME CMD
CogCM1Profile
CogCM2Profile
CogGW1Profile
CogGW2Profile
CogRS1Profile
CogRS2Profile
CogRS3Profile
```

Now if I could only append the rest of the command output,   I would love to yield a result like this.

```
Profile       UID      PID        PPID   C   STIME   TTY   TIME  CMD
CogCM1Profile wasadmin 3540106       1   0   Mar 11      -  3:01 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=47507 
CogCM2Profile wasadmin 3211972       1   0   Mar 11      -  3:35 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=47946 
CogGW1Profile wasadmin 1639922       1   0   Mar 11      -  4:16 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=47722 
CogGW2Profile wasadmin 3866760       1   0   Mar 11      -  7:18 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=42506 
CogRS1Profile wasadmin 3670356       1   1   Mar 11      - 20:43 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=46643 
CogRS2Profile wasadmin 3932926       1   0   Mar 13      - 12:37 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=50583 
CogRS3Profile wasadmin 2294788       1   0   Mar 13  pts/6 10:11 /APPS/IBM/WebSphere/AppServer_std/java/bin/java -Declipse.security -Dwas.status.socket=50452
```

Comment: My final result is a single line command , no longer using the call to "body"     ps -ef | ( sed -n "1 s/^/   WASProfile /p; s/.*\($egrepString\).*/\1 &/p" | sort -k1 ) | cut -c1-158

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you're attempting correctly, then

```
#                                               vv-- here
ps -ef | ( body sed -n "s/.*\($grepString\).*/\1 &/p" | sort -k1 )
```

should work. `&` in the replacement part of a sed `s` command refers to the thing the regex matched, which is in this case the entire line.

In order to fix the headers, you could throw in a replacement that only concerns the first line as follows:

```
ps -ef | ( body sed -n "1 s/^/Profile  /p; s/.*\($grepString\).*/\1 &/p" | sort -k1 )
```

The amount of spaces may require variation (I have no AIX to test any of this).

Comment: Thank you ,  You answered my main question.  Inserting the " & " did the trick.  I still had to cut the line     As to modifying the Header, I was using a function " body "  to strip out the header from the PS command.    I did not get the desired result when using your suggestion.   By not using the body function, I was able to get exactly what I wanted.  it works because of leading spaces of the header works for an ascending sort